# Menu in Account Object header no longer appears after adding custom component to org

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

Lightning Experience header no longer appears after adding custom component to page

I've added a custom component to my org, but now the header for standard object pages no longer loads properly. In test this was working fine.

Before:

[image]

After:
[image]

Also Activity/Chatter functionality has become broken.

I know this isn't much to go by, but does anyone know what could drive this issue? As I mentioned before, this only happens after moving the change set with these components/classes to the production org.

Comment: By header do you mean the buttons? or the inforamtion under the button?

Comment: Yes, the buttons are completely gone. The Chatter/Activity button to Add/Share are also gone.

Comment: Did you check if the standard components Chatter and Highlight panels were removed from the page layout by mistake

Comment: Yes, they were not. If I remove my lightning action from the Account page everything appears again properly.

Comment: Did you check the component code to see if there is any kind of navigatetoURL/naviagetocomponent components? I would even check if there are selective filters applied to show / hide components based on the account data if you are on a winter 18 org

Comment: post your before and after page url. From the url you can clearly say if it is loading the standard account page or if the component is navigating to a diffrent URL/ component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update for others:**  After a lot of back and forth talk the buttons were getting messed up due to the force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader Interface, nothing to do with navigation.

From the behavior you are reporting I am sure the custom component you are embedding inside your account layout has some kind of navigation behavior. If you take a look at the URL it no more says "one/one.app#/sObject/001xxxxxxxxxxxxx/view" it is replaced by /one/one.app#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

In your case I am suspecting the component has a force:editrecord component or lightning:recordViewForm (if you are on winter 18) that only shows the account related information.

eg: My component

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:actionOverride,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.navigateToMyComponent}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

Inside the navigatetochildcomponent I am just showing a datatable. Take a look at the output, all the header and highlight panel info will be cleared on loading the account record.

```
({
    navigateToMyComponent : function(component, event, helper) {
        var record_id = component.get("v.recordId");
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef : "c:navigatetochildcomponent",
            componentAttributes: {
                parent_id:record_id
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
    }
})
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't look to be the case but I think there may be something similar. The URL does not change, it includes /view at the end. I do have an init that clears out some stuff.

sObject/0014600000k4fUxAAI/view - before
sObject/0014600000k4fUxAAI/view - after

Comment: Check if there is a navigation component, that could be tour answer on why the page is not rendering the standard components

Comment: Can you post the complete component and controller

Comment: Inspecting the html before/after, I noticed anything in <div>s with forceActions (or actionsContainer) is not appearing normally. I wonder if it has to do with this?

For example, <div> with error (completely empty):

https://imgur.com/a/c7sqb

No error (everything there!):

https://imgur.com/a/Qn0nZ

Comment: Tough to say witjout looking at the component. If you are suspecting your custom component might be messing up standard salesforce components, that is not possible at all if you have activated locker service. Locker makes sure doms cannot mess each other when rendered from different domains

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to post the component(s) here. Is there a place to private message you it? Thank you!